# Insert Query is not working with phpexcel Script

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpexcel

I am using phpExcel library for import data from excel(csv) file into mysql data. Every thing is working fine except mysql insert query below is my source code. Please after review my codes let me know where is problem. I have tried with an array but im fail too. Please review my mysql query and let me know which query will be better in this PhpExcel Library. Thanks in advance.

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("myfile.csv");
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
  $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
  $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
  $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
  $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
  $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
  for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++) {
    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO myTableName (`title`) VALUES ('$cell')");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you are not checking the result of `mysql_query`. For another, you are not escaping `$cell` before putting it into the query. Finally and most important, the `mysql_` functions are being **deprecated** and will not be supported in the future.

You should use `mysqli_` functions or [PDO](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead, which handle a lot of this for you. If you use PDO, the code could look like this:

```
// open the db connection - code taken from PHP's PDO examples:
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

// throw exceptions when queries fail instead of normal errors
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$dbh->beginTransaction();
try {
  // your phpexcel code goes here

  // prepare the query - only needs to be done once
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO myTableName (`title`) VALUES (?)");

  // insert each row
  for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++) {
    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();

    $stmt->execute(array($cell));
  }
  $dbh->commitTransaction();
} catch(Exception $E) {
  $dbh->rollbackTransaction();
  throw $E;
}
```

Comment: hi Dcoder,

thanks for your response. My problem has been resolved for insert data into database. But another problem has been occored. I have an excel file with field 'Description(May be more than 1000 characters in each cell)' including 248 rows right now. When i try to insert it into database table insert then first 92 lines executed into database. Can you assist me regard this matter why phpExcel is limiting this. In near future may be excel rows should be more than 50000. Please tell me how can i handle large files data. Thanks

Comment: I got it. The description cell contains on html elements i.e{<table>, <p>, <b> font so on....}. Each excel cell is heavy therefore i need proper method which will deal with html. Is there any function or method in phpexcel that will handle this html cell data and take it from excel and insert into database from start to end? If yes please give me at least one example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that $cell contains an actual scalar value and not a rich text object before setting it in your database query. If it contains a rich text object, you will need to cast this to string (it does have a magic __toString method, and also a public getPlainText() method).

Then follow DCoder's advice regarding switching to MySQLi or PDO prepared statements rather than the old deprecated MySQL, and database error handling.

Comment: hi MarkBaker,

thanks for your response. My problem has been resolved for insert data into database. But another problem has been occored. I have an excel file with field 'Description(May be more than 1000 characters in each cell)' including 248 rows right now. When i try to insert it into database table insert then first 92 lines executed into database. Can you assist me regard this matter why phpExcel is limiting this. In near future may be excel rows should be more than 50000. Please tell me how can i handle large files data. Thanks

Comment: There is plenty of information and answers on handling large Excel files both here and on the PHPExcel forums... cell caching is the best method

Comment: I got it. The description cell contains on html elements i.e{<table>, <p>, <b> font so on....}. Each excel cell is heavy therefore i need proper method which will deal with html. Is there any function or method in phpexcel that will handle this html cell data and take it from excel and insert into database from start to end? If yes please give me at least one example. Thanks